# Is there a way I can intelligently hide the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I want the taskbar to be hidden only when there is a maximized window on screen and active, but if I have a window that isn't active then it shows. I've tried taskbar activate and that gets a bug with the start button and messes with a bunch of the smoothness of it. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: anyone? I guess this counts as my first bump on this site...